# How do you format and print multiple data types in single statement using `println`?

Tags: java, printing, format

So basically I'm trying to complete a school problem in which I have to declare two variables:

I want to print them in a single statement, but I don't know how.

I have tried using commas, and even a plus sign to separate the different variables but I'm always getting an error.

I did look online, but I guess you can only combine strings and ints?

```
Boolean isTrue = false;
Double money = 99999.99;
System.out.println(money + isTrue);
```

I expected it to print:

```
99999.99 false
```

Comment: `System.out.println(money + " " + isTrue);`

Comment: Not a Java expert but have you tried `System.out.print()`? You can print both in one line with this method but you'll need to call it twice for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate them with string:

```
Boolean isTrue = false;
Double money = 99999.99;
System.out.println(money + " " + isTrue);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Inside of a System.out.println() method each variable calls it`s string representation to print. But if it`s a primitive datatype--> then we need to call it`s to string method to print it`s exact value.

You can concatenate with .toString() method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean isTrue = false;
    Double money = 99999.99;
    System.out.println(money + isTrue.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because println will automatically convert its input to a string for printing. Any logic inside of the "()" will be performed first, before this type conversion. Since you have 2 different value types that can't normally be added together, this logic fails. You will need to convert all of your values to a string to be able to use the "+" as a concatenation.

Alternatively, consider looking at using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) or [StringFormat](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-format-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
System.out.println(money + " " + (isTrue ? "True" : "False"));
```

or simply:

```
System.out.println(money + " " + isTrue);
```